# Visual Studio 2015 Corrupting Files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, corruption

Is anyone else experiencing an intermittent issue with VS2015 (Professional) corrupting files? My installation is corrupting on average a file a day at present. It seems to happen first thing in the morning when I boot up and start work for the day. I have been able to retrieve the files from source control so far, but it's frustrating and I'm concerned I'll end up checking in a corrupt file at some point. I can't seem to find anything on Google relating to this issue. My boss has experienced similar issues but with a lower frequency. Any ideas?

Comment: Which files are getting corrupt and what's the nature of the corruption? Have you checked that your disk drive is OK?

Comment: Any type of file within the solution appears to be susceptible. I'm not experiencing any other issues with the machine. The files are just totally scrambled, the characters are all gibberish and on one line.